# Server Error in '/AmrWebServiceWS' Application. Runtime Error on WSO2AM 3.0.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I've used the option to create a REST API with a SOAP endpoint from WSO2 API Manager, it imports the WSDL and fully creates the API Definition and resources, but it just doesn't work.

When i try to make any request (from another machine, or even in the same machine) I always get this `Server Error in '/AmrWebServiceWS' Application` error.

[image: Server Error in '/AmrWebServiceWS' Application Error]

I tried creating this example `web.config` on the wso2am root folder, and on the bin folder, but it doesn't change the error, also, local request also result in this exact screen.

I know the problem isn't in the (SOAP) endpoint itself because I followed the exact same procedure to create the API on a locally installed wso2am, and it all works just fine, I'm able to make the REST requests to my local wso2am and get the results in JSON.

There also isn't anything on `wso2carbon.log`, weirdly, it doesn't print anything when a request is made, not even an error, just nothing. I also couldn't find anything about this on Google, so I'm basically giving up.

Comment: "I did the same thing on a locally installed wso2am, and it works just fine"  whats this means?

Comment: @chashikajw i followed the exact same procedure to create a REST API from the same SOAP endpoint, and it worked, i'm able to make the REST requests and get the results in JSON. I'll clarify the question!